# Event when an element becomes the URL target

Tags: javascript

I have an anchor:

```
<a href=anotherpage.php?page=1#id>go to id</a>
```

and a paragraph:

```
<p id="id">Here you now</p>
```

I want to change color of the paragraph element for one second, when the visitor follows a link to it.

Comment: The onfocus callback works for all elements afaik.

Comment: Are you sure? Cause don't worked. And on w3scool wrote: 'Execute a JavaScript when an input field gets focus:'

Comment: Rule 1: Don't trust W3Schools.

Comment: What you mean by focus a paragraph ? you cant to select it when you click or what exactly?

Comment: Why would you need to focus on a paragraph anyways. As far as I know, it won't do anything. I'd just leave it to inputs and textareas

Comment: Zakaria Acharki, I mean after I clicked on link and now on another page with some #id

Comment: are you trying to mouseover on p because focus involves some click like input..if it mouseover ..check this one - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oLzoQd

Comment: Naga Sai A, It's working and kind of solution, but what to do after that? I need to change color only for one sec, and another time when I will  read paragraph if it will be mouse over paragraph it will change color again and again.

Comment: Whoops, I thought he was trying to focus on an input. My bad.

Comment: W3Schools == Wikipedia  , everybody can write (also W3Schools is not W3C's)

Comment: Is this paragraph on another page? If so...is one second going to be too slow or perhaps too fast? If the temporary highlight is not dependent upon loading the page, then how are you guaranteed that the user will see said highlight? If this paragraph is on the same page, I got a simple solution...

Answer (score -1):

You need to do two things:

1. Add tabindex property to the paragraph DOM Element to make it focusable.
2. Register an onFocus() handler for the paragraph Element.

E.g.

```
<p id="id" tabindex="1">Here you now</p>


$("#id").focus(function() {
    $(this).css("background","red");
    var _this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        _this.css("background","none");
    }, 1000);
});
```

NOTE: I dont think the page=1#id will cause a focus event for the paragraph element.

As for the Anchor element you could have this.

```
<a href="#id" onclick="$($(this).attr('href')).focus()">go to id</a>
```

Comment: _I dont think the page=1#id will cause a focus event for the paragraph element._    That's a problem that I try to solve.